# how to refresh web-view when app is closed/removed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I want refresh web-view after every 10 minute and
the condition is that webview should reload if application is in recent or application is remove from recent.

If you have any idea about this functionality then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, you can achieve this by using a combination of the '**Timer**' class and the '**WidgetsBindingObserver**'. The '**Timer**' class will be used to schedule periodic reloads, and '**WidgetsBindingObserver**' will help you detect changes in the app's lifecycle, such as when it enters or exits the recent apps list.

Here's a basic example of how you can implement this:

1.First, make sure to add the '**timer_builder**' package to your '**pubspec.yaml**' file:

```
dependencies:
timer_builder: ^2.0.1
```

2.Import the necessary packages in your Dart file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timer_builder/timer_builder.dart';
```

3.Implement the main part of your Flutter app:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: MyWebViewScreen(),
  );
 }
}

class MyWebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyWebViewScreenState createState() => _MyWebViewScreenState();
}

class _MyWebViewScreenState extends State<MyWebViewScreen>
with WidgetsBindingObserver {
 Timer? _reloadTimer;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
  _reloadTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 10), (timer) {
  print("Reloading WebView");
  });
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  _reloadTimer?.cancel();
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
  super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
   print("App resumed - Reloading WebView");
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
    print("App paused");
  }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("WebView Example"),
   ),
   body: TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), builder: (context) {
     return Container();
   }),
  );
 }
}
```